# Side effect в Redux / Redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Что такое сайд эффекты в Redux? И чем это плохо?

Есть такой код связанный с redux-thunk:

```
function actionThunk() {
  return (dispath, getStore) => {
    const { data } = getStore()
    /* Что-то делаем */
  }
}
```

Мне сказали что нельзя вызывать `getStore` потому что могут быть сайд эффекты. Нужно передавать аргументы в функцию и работать с ними. Почему так и что значит могут быть сайд эффекты? Понимаю что функция не чистая получается, но всё же кажется каким-то награмаждением передача лишних аргументов неизвестно откуда. Тем более когда `actionThunk` Может в разным местах вызываться, и получается нужно следить каждый раз какие данные в какой аргумент передавать.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, в данном контексте сайд эффекты понимаются как непосредственное изменение store. Если так то нет ничего страшного в том что ты получишь store из getState и не будешь изменять непосредственно то что получишь, а создашь полную копию и будешь вносить изменения только в неё, тогда тот state который ты получишь окажется не тронутым, а сама функция - чистой